# Changing back color of button in metro ui vb

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a windows form application using visual studio-2012 with metro ui.
But, the problem is low customization support for controls in metro ui.
How can I change the back color of button in metro ui.
No property found in property windows of button and I tried `btn_save.BackColor = Color.Red` but it's not working.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be because `btn_save.UseCustomBackColor` would be *False* by default. Add `btn_save.UseCustomBackColor = True` before calling `btn_save.BackColor = Color.Red` and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: I tried "UseVisualStyleBackColor" to true and then false, but nothing works

Comment: Don't change the flag back to False. Try changing the Flag _UseCustomBackColor_ to _True_ under **Button Properties -> Metro Appearance**. Try selecting other tools (such as a checkbox, textbox, combobox, button etc.) and you could see that the button would turn Red (If your `btn_save.BackColor = Color.Red` is under `btn_save.Click`). As long as you have not clicked on any other tools, the button would stay Grey after clicking on it. This worked for me. Else, you might have something else disabled in its Properties.

Comment: I don't changed it back, I meant that I tried both of them (true and false), and no such a property found called "UseCustomBackColor", only "theme" and "style" are available under metro appearance, I changed "UseCustomBackColor" to true via code. But, Thanks for your reply and for your effort. Now I am using windows button with property "FlatStyle -> Flat"

Comment: It seems that you are using `System.Windows.Forms.Button` in a `MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm`. The flag _UseCustomBackColor_ is for a `MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton`. Also, I believe the "theme" and "style" that you were referring to might have been the Properties of the Form rather than the Button, since Windows Button does not have a **Metro Appearance** section under **Button Properties**. Could you try changing **BackColor** that is available under **Button Properties -> Appearance** to a color from the dropdown box?

Comment: form->metro form, button->metro button, property->style, theme under metro appearance (please see an uploaded image in edited question)

Comment: Could you upload a complete expanded version of the MetroButton properties?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. I tried all the 3 versions that are available online ([1.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/1.3.0), [1.3.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/1.3.5) and [1.4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/1.4.0)). All the versions include MetroButton with BackColor selection. Have you added all the 3 dll files as [reference](http://denricdenise.info/2014/09/how-to-use-winforms-modern-ui/2/) to the project? Are you using the framework version above .NET Framework 4.0? Also what is your Microsoft Visual Studio version?

Comment: yes, all dll files are included as reference, .net 4.5, vs-2012, and thanks once again for your valuable time.